# how to define ref type by flowtype?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, ref

I trying to define type of ref by flowtype in react v16.4.0
But I couldn't resolve it, so please let me know how to define it.

these are sample code.
I want to know how to define ref of Props type.

### Parents

```
export default class ParentComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    ....
    this.listRef = createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent
        listRef={this.listRef}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

### child

```
type Props = {
  listRef: Ref<>, // how to define here?
};

const ChildComponent = (props: Props) => {
  <div>
    <ul ref={props.listRef}>
    ...
    </ul>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

## modules version

```
"react": "^16.4.0",
"flow-bin": "^0.73.0",
```

Comment: FYI, if you make a working example on Flow.org/try you're more likely to get an answer/get one quickly (easier for other people to work on). It supports JSX and React.

Comment: Are there multiple parent components, or is it just `ParentComponent`?

Comment: I have just `ParentComponent `.  But does it have anything to do with it?

Comment: just trying to figure out if the type needed to be generic or not.

Answer (score 9):

Note from the future:

The type for `createRef` has changed, so this answer may be somewhat out-of-date.  The type is now `function createRef<T>(): {current: null | T}`. Everything below is retained for reference.

---

Taking a look at the [typedef for `createRef()`](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/react.js#L239), we can see it returns an object with this type:

```
{current: null | React$ElementRef<ElementType>}
```

It would be a little verbose to include that every time we wanted to specify the result of `createRef()`, so let's make a helper type. The `React$XXX` types are supposed to be internal. So we'll use the `React.XXX` types instead:

```
type ReactObjRef<ElementType: React.ElementType> = 
  {current: null | React.ElementRef<ElementType>}
```

And then we'll use it like this:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWmVMA8gEYBW2BAPAFEANlhBYAdjAAqTLAC5WeGADoRYyTLkA+OAF44NOHADeuAK5RKUxRPPDhcAD5L8a0eKl8hHzbObaAL50jMxwAArI1jDhxGDoBibBNLjCaOiR0QDCJJASmnBYAB4wkgAm6NjKKjngEPlS-JmasRDxADRwdg66JkZwwsCoMHyKVfhcvFgCZPZk2v39uPXDUOb40AAUYHGois1SrfEAlKb9xqjmzFDbu8cA3OdwMAAWQyqDw3z6rqq4lMhSnxNg9+sljNYylgbqc+sYIVgYJYJHBNk9jPwsm9hGVanlNOj4Z8RtM9CZXu9iXxgvD4QB6Ba00HGYLJUIsLHAHFHBJnYxU6ZjNiTbyzYTzdo0QKPFIreCcnF4+oFAy3Np7OAKso8056XpLOVwF4QADmLAMO3VHyGJIIKgsVk0jwRSKgKLRtP4ZWAADdGbS4Px7HBKAQyZb4tavtNAv7PXT7HHA3TvX7+scpTQgA))

```
import * as React from 'react'

type ReactObjRef<ElementType: React.ElementType> = 
  {current: null | React.ElementRef<ElementType>}

type ParentProps = {}

class ParentComponent extends React.Component<ParentProps, null> {
  listRef: ReactObjRef<'ul'>

  constructor(props: ParentProps) {
    super(props);
    this.listRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent
        listRef={this.listRef}
      />
    );
  }
}

type ChildProps = {
  listRef: ReactObjRef<'ul'>,
};

const ChildComponent = (props: ChildProps) => {
  const hoge = props.listRef.current;
  return (
    <div>
      <ul ref={props.listRef}>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I tried it, but I cannot access to `current`.  Do you know how to fix it?  ([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWcACspQHYyvFjoBeOAG8AvnVwAbNOnZcYAYRKROWbnCwAPGGoAm6bHhgA6JeAiruAHjlqefVABo4nAK6TJAPhE04cScCoMNgEAFyYVCYhVozMEARsHHZmKnaevnAZuBZBUK740AAUYA7htty8EPwAlD5+fqiuzFDFDtUA3Bl+MAAWgcYBQSFwQob4xriUyDohhR0Z4hlculgttcJdcJQwrlCccIWbflYKfZK6KRZ2R-WDwVgEAsK9-Xch4vX1APTpn-N+4kWsRYp2A50q-BGdX8gXuYQiRmM0WB8US8kulhgnkcNFEnRo2U4QTgoPOGLsUNaVVQ4VJughqFqAm8Gz8hOJPQgAHMWEIStSBrCQhNdvJOn5trt9odPlZdMAAG6-T5wKzuLYPJ78-iCoYPUTK2VfdyG1VfeVKjLVXE0IA))

Comment: @sottar, I updated my answer. Seems like `React.Ref<typeof Component>` isn't as straightforward as I thought.

Comment: thank you very much, but in my local project, it's dose not work....  this error was occurred.  

`Cannot create ul element because in property ref:` `• Either ParentComponent [1] is incompatible with HTMLUListElement [2] in property current.` `• Or a callable signature is missing in ReactObjRef [3] but exists in function type [4]`

Do you know something about this error?

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my answer. Rewriting it.

Comment: Updated my answer. It seems like the proper `ElementType` in this case is `'ul'`. Judging by the docs, `React.ElementRef<'ul'>` should be an `HTMLUListElement` ( https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-elementref )

Comment: This might help someone. At least for flow-bin 0.83.0, this is what I use in my props: `{..., innerRef?: ?{current: React$ElementRef<'div'> | null}, ...}`. Note the prop name (and its optional requirement) and the `div` should be changed to suite.

Answer (score 3):

I've now created a helper type for myself to abstract away the details:

```
// shared/types.js

export type ReactRefT<T> = { current: ?T }

// myComponent.jsx
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  /* ... */
  myRef: ReactRef<SomeOtherComponent> = React.createRef()
}
```

Comment: I ended up using: `type ReactRef<T> = { current: T | null }` and then I had to, and I mean, after 6 hours of fighting this, I had to use ReactRef<any>.

Answer (score 2):

Using Flow 0.102, I get perfect typing with:

```
const componentRef = {| current: null | React.ElementRef<typeof MyComponent> |} } = React.createRef<MyComponent>()
```

Answer (score 0):

Note it does not work for stateless functional components as described in Flow https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-elementref

Beware it can happen with higher order components.